# Kotlin - Spring - Endpoint Enum conversion

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, validation, enums, implicit-conversion

I have this :

```kotlin
@RestController("/test")
class MyController(
    private val myService: MyService
) {

    @RequestMapping(value = ["/test"], method = [ RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET ])
    fun redirect(myDto: MyDto) = ModelAndView("redirect:".plus(myService.getUrlFrom(myDto)))

}
```

```kotlin
class MyDto(
    prop1: MyEnum
    prop2: String
    prop3: MySecondEnum
)
```

```kotlin
enum class MyEnum(val value: String) {
    VALUE_1("value1"),
    VALUE_2("value2"),
    VALUE_3("another_value")
}
enum class MySecondEnum(val value: String) {
    A_VALUE("a"),
    B_VALUE("b"),
    C_VALUE("c")
}
```

And I want this to work :
`GET /test/test?prop1=another_value&prop2=anything&prop3=a`

Why doesn't it work by default?
How do I proceed?
Create a global converter?

Comment: Which serialization library are you using with Spring? Jackson?

Comment: *Why doesn't it work by default?* - how would you expect the serialization library to know that the `value` property should be the one to use instead of the enum constant's name. E.g. why should it use `a` and not `A_VALUE`? Using the enum constant's name is a good default (even though I don't like to rely on it myself, because it's not refac-friendly). IMO it's normal that you have to customize it if you want something different

Comment: I didn't set the serialization library, so I use the default one, Jackson I guess
Ok but enums are very often used with a value, so I imagined that serialization could be done with the enum name as the enum value

Comment: It can, but the property could have many names, or there could be multiple properties, so in the general case it's not possible for the framework to decide automatically without any special configuration from the author of the enum

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default serialization library of Spring, which is Jackson IIRC, then you should be able to achieve what you want by using `@JsonValue` on the enum's property that you want to use instead of the constant's name:

```kotlin
enum class MyEnum(@JsonValue val value: String) {
    VALUE_1("value1"),
    VALUE_2("value2"),
    VALUE_3("another_value")
}
enum class MySecondEnum(@JsonValue val value: String) {
    A_VALUE("a"),
    B_VALUE("b"),
    C_VALUE("c")
}
```

Comment: How to know the serialization library?
I tries this and get an exception :  org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] ... Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [MyEnum] for value 'value1'

Comment: Actually I'm using "spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.6" and see 

[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.14.2:compile
in the dependency-tree